# Search function not working and not showing results in html element

Tags: javascript, html, function, dropdown, html-select

I am creating a web page, on which by clicking the dropdown options and then clicking the Display-button the user can search and load search results of external library web page url into my web page. By clicking the search-button, my web page should fire/call setSearchParameters() -function (which calls other functions related to those specific dropdown options) and load the search results on my webpage.

I have checked answers on Stackoverflow from different threads (also those automatically suggested as writing this question), but nothing seems to work. Here is my code so far. Onclick-event by clicking the Display-button should call setSearchParameters() -function and load the results for example on form element.

The problem with my code right now is that when I choose options from the dropdown list and click the Display-button, it does not load the search results at all. It does not show/display any results. I tried Axios for creating search functions for certain dropdown option combinations.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Page for library search</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--JQuery-libraries:   -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Axios -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function getFinnishBooks() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?limit=0&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FBook%2F%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22fin%22&type=AllFields')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        });

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function getEnglishBooks() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?limit=0&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FBook%2F%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22fin%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22eng%22&type=AllFields')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        });

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function getFinnishRecordings() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?sort=relevance&bool0%5B%5D=AND&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&join=AND&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22fin%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FSound%2F%22&limit=20')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        });

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function getEnglishRecordings() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?sort=relevance&bool0%5B%5D=AND&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&join=AND&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22eng%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FSound%2F%22&limit=20');
      console.log(res.data.login);
    });

    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function setSearchParameters() {
      const choice = select.value;

      if (choice == 'books' && choice == 'finnish') {
        getFinnishBooks();

      } else if (choice == 'books' && choice == 'english') {
        getEnglishBooks();
      } else if (choice == 'books' && choice == 'swedish') {
        getEnglishBooks();
      } else if (choice == 'recordings' && choice == 'finnish') {
        getFinnishRecordings();
      } else if (choice == 'recordings' && choice == 'english') {
        getFinnishRecordings();

        else if (choice == 'recordings' && choice == 'swedish') {
          getFinnishRecordings();
        }
      }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- /*Style begins*/ -->
  <style>
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    /* Modify the background color */
    
    .navbar-custom {
      /*background-color: #AB47BC;*/
      background-color: #4A148C;
    }
    
    .navbar-collapse .collapse {
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      background-color: #FFEBEE;
    }
    
    iframe {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- /* Style ends */ -->
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Search library books and other stuff!</h1>
    <p>Search library books, recordings and other products from the library selection</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /*

*/ -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="example">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#option-droup-demo').multiselect({
            enableClickableOptGroups: true
          });
        });
      </script>
      <select id="option-droup-demo" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="Material">
          <option value="books">Books</option>
          <option value="recordings">Recordings</option>
          <optgroup label="Languages">
            <option value="finnish">Finnish</option>
            <option value="english">English</option>
            <option value="swedish">Swedish</option>
          </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <form>
    <!-- <button type="submit" onclick="return setSearchParameters();">Submit</button> -->
    <input type="button" onclick="setSearchParameters()" value="Display">
  </form>
</body>
<footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
  <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); margin-top: 1%; background-color: #4A148C; color: #FFFFFF; margin-bottom:0%">

    <a class="text-white" href="https://finna.fi/">Original page</a>
  </div>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Many console errors

Comment: you have invalid semicolons after most your fetch and some fetch are incomplete. Also you have not loaded a multiselect library and you have a select.value where you have not defined an object called select. That is just some of the many issues

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid semicolons after most your fetch and some fetch are incomplete. Also you have not loaded a multiselect library and you have a select.value where you have not defined an object called select. That is just some of the many issues

This no longer gives errors

But `if (choice == 'books' && choice == 'finnish') {` is never going to work

so I changed to two drop downs - now we only get network errors because of CORS issues

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Page for library search</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--JQuery-libraries:   -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Axios -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function getFinnishBooks() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?limit=0&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FBook%2F%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22fin%22&type=AllFields')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        })

        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function getEnglishBooks() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?limit=0&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FBook%2F%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22fin%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22eng%22&type=AllFields')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        })

        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function getFinnishRecordings() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?sort=relevance&bool0%5B%5D=AND&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&join=AND&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22fin%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FSound%2F%22&limit=20')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        })

        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function getEnglishRecordings() {
      axios.get('https://finna.fi/Search/Results?sort=relevance&bool0%5B%5D=AND&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&lookfor0%5B%5D=&type0%5B%5D=AllFields&join=AND&filter%5B%5D=%7Elanguage%3A%22eng%22&filter%5B%5D=%7Eformat%3A%220%2FSound%2F%22&limit=20')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.login);
        })

        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function setSearchParameters() {
      const material = $("#material").val()
      const language = $("#language").val()


      if (material == 'books' && language == 'finnish') {
        getFinnishBooks();

      } else if (material == 'books' && language == 'english') {
        getEnglishBooks();
      } else if (material == 'books' && language == 'swedish') {
        getEnglishBooks();
      } else if (material == 'recordings' && language == 'finnish') {
        getFinnishRecordings();
      } else if (material == 'recordings' && language == 'english') {
        getFinnishRecordings();
      } else if (material == 'recordings' && language == 'swedish') {
        getFinnishRecordings();
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- /*Style begins*/ -->
  <style>
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    /* Modify the background color */
    
    .navbar-custom {
      /*background-color: #AB47BC;*/
      background-color: #4A148C;
    }
    
    .navbar-collapse .collapse {
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      background-color: #FFEBEE;
    }
    
    iframe {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- /* Style ends */ -->
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Search library books and other stuff!</h1>
    <p>Search library books, recordings and other products from the library selection</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /*

*/ -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="example">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#option-droup-demo').multiselect({
                    enableClickableOptGroups: true
                  });
                }); */
      </script>
      <select id="material">
        <optgroup label="Material">
          <option value="books">Books</option>
          <option value="recordings">Recordings</option>
      </select>
      <select id="language">


        <optgroup label="Languages">
          <option value="finnish">Finnish</option>
          <option value="english">English</option>
          <option value="swedish">Swedish</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <form>
    <!-- <button type="submit" onclick="return setSearchParameters();">Submit</button> -->
    <input type="button" onclick="setSearchParameters()" value="Display">
  </form>
</body>
<footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
  <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); margin-top: 1%; background-color: #4A148C; color: #FFFFFF; margin-bottom:0%">

    <a class="text-white" href="https://finna.fi/">Original page</a>
  </div>
</footer>

</html>
```